# TortoiseGit: how to change date format in "Git command progress" window?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I use Git+TortoiseGit on Windows. I want to hide date/time stamp in the "You performed push to repo, date NNNNNNNNNNNN" window (not exact caption).

[image: window]

How to hide this date/time stamp or make it short (only show DDMMYYYY)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find first the code which prints that message:

```
git clone https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit
cd TortoiseGit

P:\git\TortoiseGit>grep -nRHI "\"Success" *
src/Resources/TortoiseProcENG.rc:3845:    IDS_SUCCESS             "Success"

P:\git\TortoiseGit>grep -nRHI "IDS_SUCCESS" *
src/TortoiseProc/SyncDlg.cpp:1176:                      temp.LoadString(IDS_SUCCESS);
```

So the code in which you can see that dialog message being built is one from the [`CSyncDlg::OnProgressUpdateUI()` method](https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit/blob/master/src/TortoiseProc/SyncDlg.cpp#L1171-L1180):

```
if (m_pTaskbarList)
    m_pTaskbarList->SetProgressState(m_hWnd, TBPF_NOPROGRESS);
CString temp;
temp.LoadString(IDS_SUCCESS);
CString log;
log.Format(_T("\r\n%s (%d ms @ %s)\r\n"), temp, tickSpent, strEndTime);
CProgressDlg::InsertColorText(this->m_ctrlCmdOut, log, RGB(0,0,255));
```

With [`strEndTime` being](https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit/blob/master/src/TortoiseProc/SyncDlg.cpp#L1146):

```
CString strEndTime = CLoglistUtils::FormatDateAndTime(CTime::GetCurrentTime(), DATE_SHORTDATE, true, false);
```

Unless you recompile TortoiseGit with a different code, there doesn't seem to be a way to easily modify that date format.

Comment: Maybe variable `strEndTime` (from code above) is built using some format option? Or is it fixed string.

Comment: @Ingo I have added `strEndTime` definition: again a matter of code, not configuration.